# Standalone Magento Google Pay plugin

Tags: payment, plugin, google

Is there any standalone plugin for Google Pay that I could use in M1 an M2?

I do not want to use any hosted plugins such as Braintree or Stripe.

I know that there is API from Google itself, but I thought about a plugin that can be easily installed.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no exclusive Magento (1 or 2) module available to integrate Google Pay with Magento. You can find an [interesting discussion regarding this in Magento Payment Improvements section on Github](https://github.com/magento/payment-improvements/issues/12).

If you want to develop a Magento Module using Google Pay API, [this Google Pay PHP library should be your starting point](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/samples/quickstart-php).

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Now there is an official extension is available in Magento 2 Market place for [Google Pay](https://marketplace.magento.com/unboundcommerce-module-googlepay.html)

Though one has to buy one of the external service from below list to process payment.

- Adyen
- BlueSnap
- Braintree
- FirstData
- Payeezy
- Moneris
- Stripe
- Vantiv

Answer (score 0):

Google Pay provides an API that allows you to integrate it with your Magento 1 or Magento 2 store. However, there is no standalone plugin available for Google Pay that can be easily installed.

To integrate Google Pay with your Magento store, you will need to develop a custom integration using the Google Pay API. This will require some technical expertise and development skills. The Google Pay API documentation provides detailed instructions and resources to help you get started with the integration process.

Alternatively, you can consider using a third-party payment gateway that supports Google Pay, such as Braintree or [Stripe in the marketplace](https://marketplace.magento.com/magenest-module-stripe-global.html), which offer pre-built integrations for Magento.